# Difference in the technology used by the team viewer and chunkvnc

Tags: anti-virus, vnc, remote-access

We are using chunkvnc . when we compile the winvnc.exe we get instancesupport.exe and it is given to the customer Which is blocked by the antivirus . After lot of searching we did not find any solution why it has been blocking. why does the AV block Chunkvnc ?
Team viewer works fine . What is the difference in the technology used by the team viewer and chunkvnc ?

Comment: The reason Teamviewer works fine is because you go through Teamviewer, VNC is a direct connection, much easier to block.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, and you probably worked it out already....

But my understanding is that its not the actual program itself that is the getting caught by antivirus software. Antivirus software is picking up the wrapper which effectively installs the remote software. It uses a form of scripting which the antivirus thinks could be dangerous.